# Parameters.AddWithValue not working

Tags: asp.net, sql, parameters, odbc

I have the following code (query abbreviated):

```
string q_sel = @"SELECT c.editedBy, c.*
                 FROM wf.chan c
                 WHERE date(editedTime) >= current_date - ? AND editedBy = '?') c2
                 ORDER BY editedTime";

if (myConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    OpenDb();

myCommand = new OdbcCommand(q_sel, myConnection);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@0", Request.QueryString["days"]);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", Request.QueryString["user"]);

OdbcDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

The query works if I manually replace the `?` with const values, but with `Parameters.AddWithValue` it does not, any idea why?

Comment: Do you need the '' around the parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AddWithValue assumes (sometime making errors) the datatype of the parameter from the value passed as its second argument. So your line

```
 myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@0", Request.QueryString["days"]);
```

pass a string for the first parameter, not a number as it seems you are expecting.
I will try to change that line in

```
 myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@0", Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["days"]));
```

Consider also to use a specific Parameter created by your code where you can set the DataType and the Size

```
OdbcParameter p = new OdbcParameter("@0", OdbcType.Int)
p.Value = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["days"]))
myCommand.Parameters.Add(p);
```

or even better a one-liner like

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@0", OdbcType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["days"]);
```